# MAAS on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dhcp, maas

I just upgraded a Ubuntu 12.04 server to 12.10.

It was built with MAAS but no other servers had been added to its private network yet, but I confirmed that dnsmasq was setup correctly for DHCP and iptables for forwarding, etc...
Now I that I have upgraded to 12.10, DHCP is no longer available and I found that dnsmasq was removed. 
What is controlling DHCP now, and where do I edit the correct configuration. This has to be done before I build the other servers and my small testing cloud.

Comment: Which server did you upgrade? The one running MAAS, or a server deployed with MAAS?

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of MAAS, including your new version, use the ISC dhcp server.  A separate package maas-dhcp acts as a wrapper, running its own instance of the dhcpd in a customized configuration.

As you'd expect, maas-dhcp depends on isc-dhcp-server.

Why the change?  If I recall correctly, the main reason for the switch from dnsmasq to the ISC server was that the former was considered a bit of an unknown at larger-scale deployments, whereas ISC's dhcpd is a proven component.